# how to save many records in a table Laravel Eloquent (no relationship)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to be able to save many rows in a row in a table, i have read that this can be done using the `create` method, but I am getting this error when trying to using the method

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `person_roles` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-01-30 07:46:19, 2019-01-30 07:46:19))

my code

```
    $data = [
        ['name' => 'actor'],
        ['name' => 'translator'],
        ['name' => 'director'],
        ['name' => 'stageDirector'],
        ['name' => 'costume'],
        ['name' => 'musical'],
        ['name' => 'supportDirector'],
        ['name' => 'photographer'],
        ['name' => 'choreographer'],
    ];

    $personRoles = PersonRole::create($data);
```

I my using Laravel v5.7.21

Updated, inside my PersonRole i have added this line

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];
```

in order for the mass assigning to work, but I am still getting the error.

Comment: Do you try to foreach your data, and create with each data ?

Comment: yes, this will work with a foreach, but i think there is a way using Eloquent to create them all at once... i am not sure, thats why i want to ask here.

Comment: Have you added "name" in the fillable property of model?

Comment: You can add it like this - 
protected $fillable = ['name'];

Comment: yes i did actually

Comment: Can you try with a single record, whether it is working or not? like data= ['name' => 'dummy'] and then save it.

Comment: foreach($data as $datas){PersonRole::create(['name'=>$datas->name])}? Something like that?

You can remove the name in your array $data just make it $data = ['actor','translator',....] will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be use `insert()` method, but when you use insert method you must be manually insert `created_at`, and `updated_at` columns

```
$data = [
    [
        'name' => 'actor',
        'created_at' => now(),
        'updated_at' => now(),
    ],
    ['name' => 'translator'],
    ['name' => 'director'],
    ['name' => 'stageDirector'],
    ['name' => 'costume'],
    ['name' => 'musical'],
    ['name' => 'supportDirector'],
    ['name' => 'photographer'],
    ['name' => 'choreographer'],
];

$personRoles = PersonRole::insert($data);
```

Comment: This solution will add Null to created_at and updated_at columns!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE :**

in your case

```
foreach($data as $datas){PersonRole::create(['name'=>$datas->name])}
```

or

```
$now = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
PersonRole::insert([
    ['name'=>'Foo', 'created_at'=>$now, 'updated_at'=>$now],
    ['name'=>'Bar', 'created_at'=>$now, 'updated_at'=>$now],
    ['name'=>'Baz', 'created_at'=>$now, 'updated_at'=>$now],
    ..................................
]);
```

or make function in model class and call it

```
public function createManyRecord(array $records){
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        $this->create($record);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: but `createMany` function is when there is a relationship, like in your demo, there is a relationship between post and comments, but i don't have any relationship, so i don't think this is the right and working choose!?

Comment: `createMany` will not work if there is no relashipship, like in my case

Comment: in your case **PersonRole::createMany($data);**

Comment: this is giving me an error `Call to undefined method App\PersonRole::createMany()`

Comment: The only way to use the **foreach** in data or do **foreach** in model functions

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `insert` instead of create-

```
$personRoles = PersonRole::insert($data);
```